# export org that has latex formular to odt failed

Tags: emacs

I followed this doc: http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-LaTeX-math-snippets.html#fn-1

install perl-latexml on my ArchLinux, my emacs is 25.1.1 + spacemacs

My org has one latex formular, when config the following line in emacs, export to odt failed

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."
  (require 'org)
  (require 'org-chinese-utils)
  (ocus-enable)
  (setq org-latex-to-mathml-convert-command
        "latexmlmath \"%i\" --presentationmathml=%o")
  )
```

> Formatting LaTeX using mathml OpenDocument export failed: Wrong type
>   argument: integer-or-marker-p,

How to fix this, I do not know what causes this problem?

If I remove the configuration in .spacemacs, export works, but no latex formular converted.

```
(setq org-latex-to-mathml-convert-command
    "latexmlmath \"%i\" --presentationmathml=%o")
```

Comment: Does it work in non-Spacemacs Emacs?  If so, you should probably file a bug report on Spacemacs.  BTW, don't forget about emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the odt dispatcher. In the function org-odt--translate-latex-fragments (see ox-odt.el) the function org-format-latex is called with the wrong arguments (or wrong order). I actually believe that this function was changed, and perhaps not all of the dispatchers were updated properly. Anyway, the bug was fixed in late 2016. Here is a link to the [patch](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/lisp/ox-odt.el?id=73694b21d7233c88bbd6e67eefaf8f4c321e4863).

Comment: Yes, after upgrading package in spacemacs, then found the bug is fixed in ox-odt.el

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same problem. My system is identical using Arch Linux, Emacs 25.1.1 and spacemacs. I also installed perl-latexml and configured emacs accordingly.

The error message is

> OpenDocument export failed: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, "/path/to/folder/"

From my understanding the argument should be "/path/to/folder/file.org/" instead of "/path/to/folder/".

The error message is the same when I try to use dvipng or imagemagick to render the math snippets.

I also tried my older emacs config without spacemacs. The problem persists, so its independent of spacemacs.